# Set theory symbol

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm studying very basic set theory for a module and have come across this symbol: | quite a few times, although I have no idea what it means, can someone explain what it is and how it makes sense in the relation below?

The symbol is the: $\mid$ symbol.

$${R=\left\{(x,y)\in A\times A\mid x-y=1\right\}}\subseteq A\times A.$$

Comment: You can read it as *such that*. In that particular example $R$ is the set of the order pairs $(x,y)\in A\times A$ such that $x-y=1$.

Comment: Other common symbols for *such that* are "$:$" and "$\ni$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, it means something along the lines of "such that," "for which," "satisfying," or "with the property that" (these phrases can usually be used interchangeably). Sometimes you'll see a colon : used instead of |.

So, the relation you wrote could be read:
"$R$ is the set of tuples $(x, y)$ in $A \times A$ with the property that $x - y = 1$".

Answer (score 2):

The symbol $\mid$, when used with set-builder notation, as in the example you posted, can be "read" as "such that" [or "for which the following holds:"], so that $R$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(x, y) \in A\times A$, **such that** $x-y = 1$, and this set $R$ is a subset of $A\times A$.

Another symbol that is sometimes used for the same purpose is the colon `:`

---

In other contexts, $\mid$ means other things, for example: $a\mid b$ means "$a$ divides $b$".

Answer (score 0):

Reading it in english it could be translated as "such that", so your set is:

All the ordered pairs $\;(x,y)\in A\times A\;$ **such that** the first coordinate minus the second one equals $\;1\;$ ...